# Zookeeper on multiple networks

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am setting up a zookeeper ensemble. However I would like to use multiple networks (each machine would have 2 IP addresses) on each node for redundancy purpose.

Can I archive this thru zookeeper configuration?

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/var/zookeeper/
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=ip1-A:2888:3888;ip2-A:2888:3888 <=?
server.2=ip1-B:2888:3888;ip2-B:2888:3888
server.3=ip1-C:2888:3888;ip2-C:2888:3888
```

Comment: How about set up a cluster of 6 nodes ?

Comment: Couldn't you just use one network and let your server HW or OS team the two NICs into one logical/virtual NIC?